# .exe file not working starting from .py file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I am new to programming. I created a very simple python script for moving the mouse every couple minutes (the code will follow) and it is working properly. Once created the .exe file of the .py script using pyinstaller, the .exe doesn't work anymore: a console opens and just does nothing. Is there anything wrong or that I am missing?

```
import time, pyautogui
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import multiprocessing


def KeepUI():
    
    sg.theme('Dark')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Keep-Me-Up is now running.\nClose it to disable it.')]
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Keep-Me-Up', layout)
    
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = dontsleep)
    p2.start()
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            if p2.is_alive(): 
                p2.terminate()
            break

def dontsleep():
    while True:
        for i in range(0,100):
            pyautogui.moveTo(1000,i*10)
            time.sleep(120)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = KeepUI)
    p1.start()
```

I tried creating the .exe file using pyinstaller (pyinstaller --onefile filename.py), as well as psgcompiler but nothing seems to work. I think I have some problems with the PySimpleGUI module

Comment: Multiprocessing with pyinstaller is notoriously hard to get to work unfortunately. I've done it before, don't remember exactly how but it involved a lot of ugly hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Windows OS. Which if that is the case then you need to enable `freeze_support` for all programs that use multiprocessing when trying to "freeze" the program / make an executable.

For example:

```
import time, pyautogui
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import freeze_support


def KeepUI():
    
    sg.theme('Dark')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Keep-Me-Up is now running.\nClose it to disable it.')]
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Keep-Me-Up', layout)
    
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = dontsleep)
    p2.start()
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            if p2.is_alive(): 
                p2.terminate()
            break

def dontsleep():
    while True:
        for i in range(0,100):
            pyautogui.moveTo(1000,i*10)
            time.sleep(120)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = KeepUI)
    p1.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're missing the filename in front of `.py` . But could you also try just with the filename without `--onefile`

```
pyinstaller filename.py
```

or use

```
pyinstaller --onefile filename.py
```

Comment: Much appreciated the answer. I don't know why but filename was not displayed in my question, I just edited it now.
Anyway it doesn't work either ways (--onefile and --onedir)